Freeradius v3.2.6 - Failed No memory!
I´m facing issues about status module to get stats in Freeradius v3.2.6
According to the debug logs, it says "Error: No memory!"
Tue Sep 24 10:54:51 2024 : Debug: (0) Received Status-Server Id 156 from 127.0.0.1:36147 to 127.0.0.1:18121
Tue Sep 24 10:54:51 2024 : Debug: (0)   Message-Authenticator = 0xb48e6f61c6b2cc37a5b4c97793c4d1ab
Tue Sep 24 10:54:51 2024 : Debug: (0)   FreeRADIUS-Statistics-Type = Accounting
Tue Sep 24 10:54:51 2024 : Error: No memory!
I simulate the query like "echo "Message-Authenticator = 0x00,FreeRADIUS-Statistics-Type = 2" | radclient -x localhost:18121 status adminsecret"
Any clue about this error log?
